# Problemas com caracteres especiais no asp.net GRIDVIEW

Tags: asp.net, string, gridview, div

Estou construindo um GRIDVIEW dinamico, onde a informação de cada TD será uma DIV.

```
exemplo: <td><div id="d1" class="redips-drag t1">z</div></td>
```

estou preenchendo a váriavél da seguinte forma:

```
if (dtWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate.Rows.Count > 0)
    finalResult = "<div id=\"column" + count.ToString() + "\" class=\"redips-drag t1\">" + formatSecondsInHourAndMinute(Convert.ToInt32(dtWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate.Rows[0]["work_ServiceTime"])) + "</div>";
```

O meu problema é que o GRID não reconhece a div como um objeto, e sim como uma String. O valor de cada coluna está saindo da seguinte forma:

```
exemplo &lt;div id=&quot;column1&quot; class=&quot;redips-drag t1&quot;&gt;23:59&lt;/div&gt;
```

Alguem sabe como posso fazer para evitar esse problema?

Vlw.

**EDIT**

Para construir o grid, estou utilizando uma função que retorna um DataTable, da seguinte forma:

```
public DataTable constructWorkerAvailabilityTime()
    {
        DateTime fDateDataType = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(fYear), Int32.Parse(fMonth), Int32.Parse(fDay));
        DateTime tDateDataType = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(tYear), Int32.Parse(tMonth), Int32.Parse(tDay));

        this.fromDate = fDateDataType.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.toDate = tDateDataType.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        DataTable dtFinalResult = new DataTable();
        List<String> allWorkers = getAllWorkers();
        List<String> columnsSequence = getDateColumnsSequence();

        dtFinalResult.Columns.Add("worker", typeof(string));

        int count = 0;

        foreach (string column in columnsSequence)
            dtFinalResult.Columns.Add(column, typeof(string));

        foreach (string worker in allWorkers)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dtFinalResult.NewRow();

            newRow["worker"] = getWorkerName(worker);

            foreach (string column in columnsSequence)
            {
                HtmlString htmlString = getWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate(worker, column, count);
                newRow[column] = htmlString;
                //newRow[column] = "@Html.Raw(" + getWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate(worker, column, count) + ")";
                count++;
            }

            dtFinalResult.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return dtFinalResult;
    }

private HtmlString getWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate(string worker, string executionDate, int count)
    {
        HtmlString finalResult = new HtmlString("");
        DataTable dtWorkServiceTimeByWorker = cmd.selectWorkServiceTimeByWorker(worker);
        DataTable dtWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate = cmd.selectWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate(worker, executionDate);

        if (dtWorkServiceTimeByWorker.Rows.Count == 1)
            finalResult = new HtmlString("<div id=\"column" + count.ToString() + "\" class=\"redips-drag t1\" runat=\"server\">" + formatSecondsInHourAndMinute(Convert.ToInt32("28860")) + "</div>");
        else if (dtWorkServiceTimeByWorker.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (dtWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate.Rows.Count > 0)
                finalResult = new HtmlString("<div id=\"column" + count.ToString() + "\" class=\"redips-drag t1\" runat=\"server\">" + formatSecondsInHourAndMinute(Convert.ToInt32(dtWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate.Rows[0]["work_ServiceTime"])) + "</div>");
            else
                finalResult = new HtmlString("<div id=\"column" + count.ToString() + "\" class=\"redips-drag t1\" runat=\"server\">00:00</div>");
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

E por fim preencho o grid no Load da página:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WorkerManagement wm = new WorkerManagement();
        GridWorkerAvailability.DataSource = wm.constructWorkerAvailabilityTime();
        GridWorkerAvailability.DataBind();
        GridWorkerAvailability.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Flavio, dá uma olhada nessa [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2168663/2630549) e vê se consegue resolver com uma dessas duas soluções, não tô podendo testar agora.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira BOAA! Resolvou meu problema, vlww cara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, utilizei:

```
    protected void GridWorkerAvailability_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int cellCount = e.Row.Cells.Count;

        for (int j = 1; j < cellCount; j++)
        {
            string encoded = e.Row.Cells[j].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[j].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `Html.Raw()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
@Html.Raw(finalResult)
```

Comment: Eai Felipe, primeiro, vlw pela ajuda. Mas vamos lá, eu tentei utilizar o que você disse, mas não sei se a sintaxe está correta, porque nao deu certo. Da uma olhada: `newRow[column] = "@Html.Raw(" + getWorkServiceTimeByWorkerAndDate(worker, column, count) + ")";` Essa função retorna o valor do finalResult.

Comment: @FlavioLuiz, essa string `finalResult` você manda pra view? Esse `@Html.Raw` tem que ser utilizado no html, mas irá depender da view engine que está utilizando (no meu exemplo, foi com razor). Poderia exemplificar como está tentando exibir esses dados?

Comment: @FilipiOliveira estou construindo um gridView dinamico, ou seja, estou construindo um DataTable, preenchendo as colunas com os respectivos valores, e na propriedade DataSource do gridView, estou inserindo o DataTable. Vou editar o código e inserir algumas funções que fazem parte da construção do grid.